# Selenium: cant get the correct coordinates of element with Python

Tags: python, selenium, web

```
url = 'https://golestan.kntu.ac.ir/home/balancer/balancer.aspx?vv=2&cost=main'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "G://captcha recognition project//chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tblCap"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/img')
location = element.location
size = element.size
```

return the size correctly but coordinates are not exact 
for example the correct coordinates are 1100 & 600
but the output is 900 & 500
any solution?????

Comment: can you tell us your usecase ?

Comment: i'm trying to find the location then crop the image by those locations

Comment: replace this `driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)` to `driver.maximize_window()`

Comment: How do you get y = 500? It is about 100

Comment: replace this driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080) to driver.maximize_window() – cruisepandey its not working i'm getting the same result!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRYSz.png

Comment: @arian calm down please, cruisepandey wants to help you.

Comment: i'm calm dude just like to using '!' no big deal :D thanks for helping

Comment: i put numbers as an instance the acurates numbers are .original :1222 125
output:  980 102

Comment: @arian: It looks an issue in chrome browser and can you try with other browser (Firefox)

Comment: i tried  Firefox  but again almost same result!

Comment: interesting fact is when i change window size i get different locations ?   
what should be the window size???
full screen?